# последовательное присвоение нескольких значений одному ключу словаря

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари

Хочу получить словарь из нескольких списков таким образом, чтобы первый эллемент из первого списка стал ключом, а его значениями - первые эллементы из остальных списков, второе значение первого списка - вторым ключом и так далее

Пример того, что хочу получить:

```
list1 = [Ivan, Fedor, Michail]
list2 = [1, 2, 3]
list3 = [alfa, beta,]

slovar = {Ivan: [1, alfa], Fedor: [2, beta], Michail: [3, ]}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import zip_longest

d = {k: list(i for i in v if i is not None) for k, *v in zip_longest(list1, list2, list3)}
```